# In a VB project, is it possible to have a resx file with the same name than a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resx

Good Morning,

I'm working in a VB project (usually I work mostly on C#) and there is an issue at the compilation that I don't understand:

In my VB project I have a Windows Form (with its own Designer.vb and .resx) and a Resources file (with its Designer.vb), both have the same name, and it seems that it produce the following compilation error:

> Error 13 The item "obj\Debug[projectName].[fileName].resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter.

I can't change the name of one of them as it's an internal design pattern (and it works in C# projects).

Doesn't VB accept such pattern ? If yes, are there any workaround possible ? 
Or do I have something wrong in one of my project files ?

Regards

Edit: As my problem may not be very clear, here is the pattern I have to respect in this project :

[image]

This doesn't compile. In VB only as I'm using this pattern in C# projects without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found where the problem was:
It was an issue with namespaces, as VB generated in VisualStudio doesn't provide any namespace by default in WinForms, ones I gave a namespace to the form and the designer of the form, and gave a different namespace to the second resx (via it's properties/Custom Tool Namespace) it compile.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a duplicated entry inside the form.designer. I ran across this problem once

Goto to your Solution Explorer, Select your project and click on the show all files icon at the top of the Solution Explorer. You should then be able to expand out your form.vb to see all the sub files. Look for a frmMain.Designer.vb and check it for a duplicate resource entry. If that doesn't work try cleaning your Solution

Extracted from here, check the link it may help:

[VB.net designer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375548/vb-net-designer-error-how-do-i-resolve-it)

Edit: I would delete the form. Save the code behind and create it with another name pasting the code.

Comment: It's what I sought first, but when I'm deleting the resx file (not the one of the form, but the second one) it's compiling. So the form seems ok.

Comment: Nace dude Im glad it compile ;)

Comment: No, it still not compiling : I can't delete the second one as I need it (it is not related to the Form)

Comment: I added an image of the pattern I need to respect. I may be more understandable. :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Try removing form saving code and create new form with other name and paste code.Give it a try

Comment: I tried this on my pattern test (cf screen shot) : -delete the form -recreate the form with the same name (as it's an obligation) -still not compiling

I tried also to recreate it with another name, and then, rename, but it's the same error.

Comment: No. I mean create with different name and change the app main form in project properties. It should work but change the name.

Comment: I can't, as the pattern use the name of the form to link data in the related resx file.
That mean that I can't keep this pattern in VB, right ?